# How can we put two bibitems (that is in form of icons) horizontally after some spaces?

Tags: bibliographies

How can we put two bibitems (that is in form of icons) horizontally after some spaces?

> [1] text1 [2] text2

Actually I need it in my `beamer`.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9} 
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[article] 
\bibitem{} (Jungck and Rhoades [72], 
\bibitem{} Padaliya and Pant [88], Pant [92,94], Pant and Pant [100], Sastry and Murthy [119], and Singh and Kumar [128]) 
\end{thebibliography} 
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Everything doesn't require example.

Comment: See I want ..... [1] text1       [2] text2

Comment: 1. I don't understand your question. What icons, what spaces... Please draw a small sketch. 2. Not everything does need an example, but every question should at least provide some code. We don't want to set up a beamer document with bibliography and a sample frame in order to help you with one command. And less we want to provide an answer which is followed by a "oh, but I am using this and that package...". That's why we always need an example.

Comment: \begin{frame}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[article]
\bibitem{} Jungck and Rhoades AND IN THE SAME LINE \bibitem{} Padaliya and Pant 
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

Answer (score 3):

What about this

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    Here's some text

    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{thebibliography}{}
    \bibitem{key1}%
        Author J., 2014
        \newblock Some great title
        \newblock {\em Journal of Universal Rejection}
    \end{thebibliography}
    \end{minipage}% <- important to suppress whitespace between "columns"
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{thebibliography}{}
    \bibitem{key2}%
        Doe J., 2011
        \newblock Another great title
        \newblock {\em Journal of Universal Rejection}
    \end{thebibliography}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @DeepeshPatel glad I could help. But please, next time consider including a compilable starting point in your question. As stated it was not clear to me what you wanted, this was a guess =)

Comment: @DeepeshPatel ah and if this solved your problem consider accepting the answer